# php append pdf to pdf and check the page template first

Tags: php, pdf

i have a form where people can upload pdfs

with fpdf I append those pdf and generate a new one.
this works ok for portraits right now. if someone uploads a portrait formatted pdf, I gets cut of, because it does not fit on portrait a4 document.
is there a way I can determine which alignment a pdf has?
this is my code to append:

```
/* APPEND PDFs */
    $files = [];
    array_push($files, $upload_folder . '/' . $pdf_name);
    if($new_path != 0 & $ext == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path);
    }
    if($new_path1 != 0  & $ext1 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path1);
    }
    if($new_path2 != 0  & $ext2 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path2);
    }
    if($new_path3 != 0  & $ext3 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path3);
    }
    if($new_path4 != 0  & $ext4 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path4);
    }
    if($new_path5 != 0 & $ext5 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path5);
    }
    if($new_path6 != 0  & $ext6 == 'pdf'){
        array_push($files, $new_path6);
    }

pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();

// iterate over array of files and merge
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pageCount; $i++) {
        $tpl = $pdf->importPage($i + 1, '/MediaBox');
        $pdf->addPage();
        $pdf->useTemplate($tpl);
    }
}

// output the pdf as a file (http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)
$pdf->Output('F',$upload_folder . '/' . $pdf_name);
```

thanks a lot

Comment: So what is a "vertical aligned pdf"? Is it a PDF in which any part of the text is "vertically aligned"? What does that mean? Perhaps an example could illustrate this. And what happens when "it does not work"?

Comment: sorry, of course. I mean the alignment of the pages. portrait vs. landscape. either the pdf is in "Landscape" or "portrait" modus. it is not mixed.

Comment: when I upload a landscape right now, it gets cut off because it does not fit on a portrait page

Comment: OK, that clarifies it completely. Thank you. Perhaps you should edit your question to make it clear there. People read your question first, and some will never get to the comments.

Comment: I see in [the FPDI manual](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#index-2) that there's a method called `getImportedPageSize()`. It can tell you what the aspect ratio of an imported page is. I think I do use FPDI myself, and I don't have the problem you describe. Checking this does require a bit of digging.

Comment: Oh, and then there is [this example](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/examples/#index-3) that shows you how you can reorient the pages depending on the source file. Your `$pdf->addPage()` is rather empty.

Comment: thank you very much. this is exactly what I am looking for!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to KIKO Software I was able to solve it with this example:

```
// iterate through the files
foreach ($files AS $file) {
    // get the page count
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
    // iterate through all pages
    for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
        // import a page
        $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
        // get the size of the imported page
        $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

        // add a page with the same orientation and size
        $pdf->AddPage($size['orientation'], $size);

        // use the imported page
        $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
        $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
        $pdf->Write(8, 'A simple concatenation demo with FPDI');
    }
}
```